# Text Editor in C select text with shift

Tags: c

I am trying to design text editor in C. For example I am creating a new text file and getting content from user until pressing `.`

```
void Create() {
    fp1 = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    printf("\n\tEnter the text and press '.' to save\n\n");
    while (1) {
        c = getchar();
        fputc(c, fp1);
        if (c == '.') {
            fclose(fp1);
            printf("\n\tEnter then new filename: ");
            scanf("%s", fn);
            fp1 = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
            fp2 = fopen(fn, "w");
            while (!feof(fp1)) {
                c = getc(fp1);
                putc(c, fp2);
            }
            fclose(fp2);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is fine till here, my problem is I wish the user could select text with the shift key and navigate in the text with the up/down arrows...

Comment: you'll need a lib for that, like curses or ncurses.

Answer (score 1):

The standard C99 or [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) (read the [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft specification) does not know about keyboards or buttons. You probably need some operating system related library.

Assuming your OS is POSIX (e.g. Linux), you want to know more about [terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal) and ttys (so read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page); then you should use a library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) (but then don't use any `<stdio.h>` function for terminal I/O).

Or you want some [graphical user interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface), then better use some [graphics library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_library) or [toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) (such as [GTK](http://gtk.org/), [SDL](http://libsdl.org/), [Qt](http://qt.io/) etc....).

You will need many months (or years) of work to make a text editor. So study the source code of existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) editors for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is not fine here. Your program has multiple issues:

- You do not define `c`, `fp1`, `fp2`, `fn`...
- You use `scanf()` in an unsafe way.
- You dont check for `EOF` when reading from `stdin`.
- You store the `.` into `temp.txt`
- Also check [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)
- Using a single character `.` as the final mark has side effects: you will not be able to use that character in the file, that's a strong limitation. You should at least only consider `.` at the start of a line.

Here is an improved version:

```
int Create(void) {
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    char fn[1024];
    int last = '\n', c;

    fp1 = fopen("temp.txt", "w+");
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot create file temp.txt\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("\n\tEnter the text and press '.' to save\n\n");
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && (c != '.' || last != '\n')) {
        fputc(c, fp1);
        last = c;
    }
    for (;;) {
        printf("\n\tEnter then new filename: ");
        if (scanf(" %1023[^\n]%*c", fn) != 1) {
            printf("input error\n");
            fclose(fp1);
            return -2;
        }
        fp2 = fopen(fn, "w");
        if (fp2 == NULL) {
            printf("Cannot create output file %s\n", fn);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    rewind(fp1);
    while ((c = getc(fp1)) {
        putc(c, fp2);
    }
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```

If you wish to write an interactive editor, you need to set the terminal in raw mode with `stty()` and use a library such as `ncurses` to handle full screen output and cursor key input.  You can also assume the terminal supports ANSI escape sequences and hard code input and output accordingly.

Such a project is quite an endeavor. I strongly suggest you look at existing open source editors, read the source code and learn how they handle various tasks. I personally co-authored an Emacs clone called `qemacs` (for Quick Emacs). You can read about it and get the source code from http://qemacs.org, but it is a large project to tackle for a beginner.

Comment: Qemacs is by F.Bellard. Are you that guy?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: No, I am not Fabrice, I co-authored qemacs with Fabrice, whom I have worked with for 18 years. Fabrice stopped working on qemacs many years ago and I am the only maintainer. Do you know FB?

Comment: Not personally, but by reputation.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:  Fabrice is by far the most proficient programmer I have ever met, in a league of his own.